# Troble finding URN of Item from BIM 360 using Autodesk Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-bim360, autodesk-data-management

We have our files in BIM 360 container. We are trying to create the viewer app which consume the BIM360 file and display it in browser, the sample code which available in Forge site for Viewer is working fine in our local environment but we are facing issue with accessing BIM360 urn in same app (we already tried with the 3- legged authentication token too ). Could you please guide us to get the right URN for the file which are stored in BIM360 container? Please find the sample URN (we have converted to base64 while accessing in viewer app)which belongs to the DWG file in BIM360 , kindly let us know whether it is right one or not.

urn:adsk.objects:os.object:wip.dm.prod/7c21a6f0-41c9-42ae-a2b2-4b5741fa4d0c.dwg
urn:adsk.objects:os.object:wip.dm.prod/9ece42b9-c71c-4a27-90bb-87775f370164.dwg

Also please find the item details response json,

```js
{
    "jsonapi": {
        "version": "1.0"
    },
    "links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/b.56fded29-645c-44b6-9498-29c0f9517fec/items/urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:1sbrvwIVRJ6J_hnfeVDA2g"
        }
    },
    "data": {
        "type": "items",
        "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:1sbrvwIVRJ6J_hnfeVDA2g",
        "attributes": {
            "displayName": "bandra ga.dwg",
            "createTime": "2021-02-16T11:06:47.0000000Z",
            "createUserId": "8DCHNK3XFCM2",
            "createUserName": "VBSL System Integrator",
            "lastModifiedTime": "2021-02-16T11:06:47.0000000Z",
            "lastModifiedUserId": "8DCHNK3XFCM2",
            "lastModifiedUserName": "VBSL System Integrator",
            "hidden": false,
            "reserved": false,
            "extension": {
                "type": "items:autodesk.bim360:File",
                "version": "1.0",
                "schema": {
                    "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/schema/v1/versions/items:autodesk.bim360:File-1.0"
                },
                "data": {
                    "sourceFileName": "bandra ga.dwg"
                }
            }
        },
        "links": {
            "self": {
                "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/b.56fded29-645c-44b6-9498-29c0f9517fec/items/urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:1sbrvwIVRJ6J_hnfeVDA2g"
            },
            "webView": {
                "href": "https://docs.b360.autodesk.com/projects/56fded29-645c-44b6-9498-29c0f9517fec/folders/urn%3Aadsk.wipprod%3Afs.folder%3Aco.nPlZOfdwQQiTrkXjS0FVVw/detail/viewer/items/urn%3Aadsk.wipprod%3Adm.lineage%3A1sbrvwIVRJ6J_hnfeVDA2g"
            }
        },
        "relationships": {
            "tip": {
                "data": {
                    "type": "versions",
                    "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.1sbrvwIVRJ6J_hnfeVDA2g?version=1"
                },
                "links": {
                    "related": {
                        "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/b.56fded29-645c-44b6-9498-29c0f9517fec/items/urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:1sbrvwIVRJ6J_hnfeVDA2g/tip"
                    }
                }
            },
            "versions": {
                "links": {
                    "related": {
                        "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/b.56fded29-645c-44b6-9498-29c0f9517fec/items/urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:1sbrvwIVRJ6J_hnfeVDA2g/versions"
                    }
                }
            },
            "parent": {
                "data": {
                    "type": "folders",
                    "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.folder:co.nPlZOfdwQQiTrkXjS0FVVw"
                },
                "links": {
                    "related": {
                        "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/b.56fded29-645c-44b6-9498-29c0f9517fec/items/urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:1sbrvwIVRJ6J_hnfeVDA2g/parent"
                    }
                }
            },
            "refs": {
                "links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/b.56fded29-645c-44b6-9498-29c0f9517fec/items/urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:1sbrvwIVRJ6J_hnfeVDA2g/relationships/refs"
                    },
                    "related": {
                        "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/b.56fded29-645c-44b6-9498-29c0f9517fec/items/urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:1sbrvwIVRJ6J_hnfeVDA2g/refs"
                    }
                }
            },
            "links": {
                "links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/b.56fded29-645c-44b6-9498-29c0f9517fec/items/urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:1sbrvwIVRJ6J_hnfeVDA2g/relationships/links"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "included": [
        {
            "type": "versions",
            "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.1sbrvwIVRJ6J_hnfeVDA2g?version=1",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "bandra ga.dwg",
                "displayName": "bandra ga.dwg",
                "createTime": "2021-02-16T11:06:47.0000000Z",
                "createUserId": "8DCHNK3XFCM2",
                "createUserName": "VBSL System Integrator",
                "lastModifiedTime": "2021-02-16T11:08:00.0000000Z",
                "lastModifiedUserId": "8DCHNK3XFCM2",
                "lastModifiedUserName": "VBSL System Integrator",
                "versionNumber": 1,
                "storageSize": 2227450,
                "fileType": "dwg",
                "extension": {
                    "type": "versions:autodesk.bim360:File",
                    "version": "1.0",
                    "schema": {
                        "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/schema/v1/versions/versions:autodesk.bim360:File-1.0"
                    },
                    "data": {
                        "processState": "PROCESSING_COMPLETE",
                        "extractionState": "SUCCESS",
                        "splittingState": "NOT_SPLIT",
                        "reviewState": "NOT_IN_REVIEW",
                        "revisionDisplayLabel": "1",
                        "sourceFileName": "bandra ga.dwg"
                    }
                }
            },
            "links": {
                "self": {
                    "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/b.56fded29-645c-44b6-9498-29c0f9517fec/versions/urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.1sbrvwIVRJ6J_hnfeVDA2g%3Fversion=1"
                },
                "webView": {
                    "href": "https://docs.b360.autodesk.com/projects/56fded29-645c-44b6-9498-29c0f9517fec/folders/urn%3Aadsk.wipprod%3Afs.folder%3Aco.nPlZOfdwQQiTrkXjS0FVVw/detail/viewer/items/urn%3Aadsk.wipprod%3Afs.file%3Avf.1sbrvwIVRJ6J_hnfeVDA2g%3Fversion%3D1"
                }
            },
            "relationships": {
                "item": {
                    "data": {
                        "type": "items",
                        "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:1sbrvwIVRJ6J_hnfeVDA2g"
                    },
                    "links": {
                        "related": {
                            "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/b.56fded29-645c-44b6-9498-29c0f9517fec/versions/urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.1sbrvwIVRJ6J_hnfeVDA2g%3Fversion=1/item"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "links": {
                    "links": {
                        "self": {
                            "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/b.56fded29-645c-44b6-9498-29c0f9517fec/versions/urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.1sbrvwIVRJ6J_hnfeVDA2g%3Fversion=1/relationships/links"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "refs": {
                    "links": {
                        "self": {
                            "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/b.56fded29-645c-44b6-9498-29c0f9517fec/versions/urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.1sbrvwIVRJ6J_hnfeVDA2g%3Fversion=1/relationships/refs"
                        },
                        "related": {
                            "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/b.56fded29-645c-44b6-9498-29c0f9517fec/versions/urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.1sbrvwIVRJ6J_hnfeVDA2g%3Fversion=1/refs"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "downloadFormats": {
                    "links": {
                        "related": {
                            "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/b.56fded29-645c-44b6-9498-29c0f9517fec/versions/urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.1sbrvwIVRJ6J_hnfeVDA2g%3Fversion=1/downloadFormats"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "derivatives": {
                    "data": {
                        "type": "derivatives",
                        "id": "dXJuOmFkc2sud2lwcHJvZDpmcy5maWxlOnZmLjFzYnJ2d0lWUko2Sl9obmZlVkRBMmc_dmVyc2lvbj0x"
                    },
                    "meta": {
                        "link": {
                            "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/dXJuOmFkc2sud2lwcHJvZDpmcy5maWxlOnZmLjFzYnJ2d0lWUko2Sl9obmZlVkRBMmc_dmVyc2lvbj0x/manifest?scopes=b360project.56fded29-645c-44b6-9498-29c0f9517fec,O2tenant.5902118"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "thumbnails": {
                    "data": {
                        "type": "thumbnails",
                        "id": "dXJuOmFkc2sud2lwcHJvZDpmcy5maWxlOnZmLjFzYnJ2d0lWUko2Sl9obmZlVkRBMmc_dmVyc2lvbj0x"
                    },
                    "meta": {
                        "link": {
                            "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/dXJuOmFkc2sud2lwcHJvZDpmcy5maWxlOnZmLjFzYnJ2d0lWUko2Sl9obmZlVkRBMmc_dmVyc2lvbj0x/thumbnail?scopes=b360project.56fded29-645c-44b6-9498-29c0f9517fec,O2tenant.5902118"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "storage": {
                    "data": {
                        "type": "objects",
                        "id": "urn:adsk.objects:os.object:wip.dm.prod/9ece42b9-c71c-4a27-90bb-87775f370164.dwg"
                    },
                    "meta": {
                        "link": {
                            "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/wip.dm.prod/objects/9ece42b9-c71c-4a27-90bb-87775f370164.dwg?scopes=b360project.56fded29-645c-44b6-9498-29c0f9517fec,O2tenant.5902118"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's here: `dXJuOmFkc2sud2lwcHJvZDpmcy5maWxlOnZmLjFzYnJ2d0lWUko2Sl9obmZlVkRBMmc_dmVyc2lvbj0x`

```json
"derivatives": {
    "data": {
        "type": "derivatives",
        "id": "dXJuOmFkc2sud2lwcHJvZDpmcy5maWxlOnZmLjFzYnJ2d0lWUko2Sl9obmZlVkRBMmc_dmVyc2lvbj0x"
    },
    "meta": {
        "link": {
            "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/dXJuOmFkc2sud2lwcHJvZDpmcy5maWxlOnZmLjFzYnJ2d0lWUko2Sl9obmZlVkRBMmc_dmVyc2lvbj0x/manifest?scopes=b360project.56fded29-645c-44b6-9498-29c0f9517fec,O2tenant.5902118"
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really helped me

Comment: i have one more question, could you please let me know whether is it possible to add the google map inside the viewer and then add the 3d model on top of it? is anyone done it ?

Comment: Searching engine of https://forge.autodesk.com/blog is your good friend by the way :)  https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/add-mapbox-google-maps-forge-viewer

Answer (score 1):

To get the storage location of the an item (in your case `urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:1sbrvwIVRJ6J_hnfeVDA2g`), query the data of the tip (latest version) of the item using **{{FORGE_HOST}}/data/v1/projects/:project/items/:item/tip** (in your case, you can simply add */tip* to your *.links.self.href*, ie. `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/b.56fded29-645c-44b6-9498-29c0f9517fec/items/urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:1sbrvwIVRJ6J_hnfeVDA2g/tip`.

This will return details of the latest version of the item ([docs](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-items-item_id-tip-GET/)).

There, you should find `data.relationships.storage.data.id`, which is the the storage urn.